# Does GCM require a Google account or not?

Tags: android

I have surfed on the net for quite a while, there are claims that Google Play account is required, and others say that it is not required. Which is correct? If possible, how could I enable GCM notification without Google account? Many thanks.

Comment: you just require a gmail account

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [document](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

> On pre-3.0 devices, **GCM** requires users to set up their Google account
>   on their mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on
>   devices running Android 4.0.4 or higher.

Therefore user need google account to use GCM in their devices (Only on pre-3.0).

Comment: @Derekyy Happy to help,enjoy.